Return custom error from @CircuitBreaker fallbackMethod
I have this resilience4j CircuitBreaker implementation which I want to migrate from Hystrix:
Hystrix endpoint:
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "group1", commandKey = "createAccount", threadPoolKey = "priority-1-pool",
        ignoreExceptions = {BadRequestException.class})
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public ResponseEntity<?> greeting() {
    .....
}

Migrated to @CircuitBreaker:
@RestController
public class Endpoint {

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "createAccount", fallbackMethod = "fallbackGetListValues")
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public ResponseEntity<?> greeting() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> fallbackGetListValues(Exception e) {

        // Return here  BadRequestException class
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Fallback response");
    }

}

How I can return this custom exception from method fallbackGetListValues?
@ResponseStatus(
        value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        reason = "You got a invalid request."
)
public class BadRequestException extends Exception{
}


Do you want to get BAD_REQUEST error code with a reason message in your expected response when call /greeting endpoint?

I want to get the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST from public class BadRequestException when I send invalid request.
